# static method and non static method Java

Tags: java

I know I'm doing something stupid, but I cannot figure how to fix it.

The issue is inside the `private` method `removeVowels` particulry when using the `vowels` method.

The compiler gives

`non-static variable vowels cannot be referenced from a static context`

Here is my code:

```
   public class RecursionHW2 {

            String vowels;

            // Part (A) First way
            public static int upperCase(String myString){

                return upperCaseChecker(myString , 0 );
            }

            public static int upperCaseChecker(String myString, int index){

                int inc;

                //My Base Code
                if(myString.length() <= index) return 0;
                if(Character.isUpperCase(myString.charAt(index)) == true) inc= 1;
                    else inc= 0;

                return inc+upperCaseChecker(myString,index+1);
            }



            // First way of Solving part (B)
            public static int count(String str, char a)
            {
                if (str.length() == 0)
                    return 0;
                else if (str.charAt(0) == a)
                    return 1 + count(str.substring(1, str.length()), a);
                else
                    return count(str.substring(1, str.length()), a);
            }


            //Second way of solving part (B)
            public static int anotherCount(String myString, char myWord)
            {
                return anotherCount(myString, myWord, 0);
            }

            public static int anotherCount(String myString, char myWord, int index)
            {
                int inc;

                if (index >= myString.length())
                {
                    return 0;
                }

                if (myString.charAt(index) == myWord)  inc =1;
                    else
                        inc = 0;

                return inc + anotherCount(myString, myWord, index+1);
            }



            // part (C) solving
            public Boolean isSorted(int[] a, int n)
            {
            if(n == 0 || n == 1) return true;
            else
            return isSorted(a, n, 1);
            }

            private Boolean isSorted(int[] a, int n, int cur)
            {
                if(cur == n) return true;

                if(a[cur - 1] <= a[cur])
                    return isSorted(a, n, cur+1);
                else
                    return false;
            }



            //part (D) Solving
            public static String removeVowels(String myString)
            {
                return removeVowels(myString, "");
            }

            private static String removeVowels(String myString, String t)
            {
                if(myString.length() == 0) return t;

                if(vowels.contains(myString.charAt(0) + ""))
                    return removeVowels(myString.substring(1), t);
                else
                    return removeVowels(myString.substring(1), t + myString.charAt(0));
            }


        public static void main(String[] args){


            //I've wrote 2 ways to solve the Second Recursive Q2
            System.out.println("Method 1: Number of Occurence " + count("Hello  This is Mohammad Fadin",'o'));
        //  System.out.println("Method 2: Number of Occurence "+ anotherCount("Hello This is Mohammad Fadin",'o'));

            String s1 = "Hello WorlDD";
            System.out.println("Number of Upper Cases " + upperCase(s1));

            String s2 = "Hello";
            System.out.println("After Vowels Removed " + removeVowels(s2));
        }


    }
```

Comment: Read the compile error message. It describes ***exactly*** what the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've "infected" your code with `static` from your `main` method.  In your `main` method you should do something like this, so you don't have to make everything `static`:

```
public class RecursionHW2
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    RecursionHW2 rhw2 = new RecursionHW2();

    int count = rhw2.count("Hello world");

    // and so on
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't think about it this way. I will try this now.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot reference an instance variable from a static context. You have to create an instance of `RecursionHW2` first, or make the variable `vowels` *static* which makes more sense. Or you might consider to remove *static* modifier from `removeVowels` method.

**Update:**
However, your class looks like a bunch of utility methods, so you may want to make it non-instantiable (by adding a private constructor), make all of your methods static (because they clearly don't operate on object's state) and pass `vowels` as an additional parameter to `removeVowels` method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is exactly what the compiler tells you: you are referencing a non-static (instance) variable `vowels` from a static context. Actually, almost all your methods are static which is an extremely bad design.

Make all methods which require access to instance data (here: `vowels` instance variable) non-static and instantiate your class in `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
String vowels;
```

to:

```
static String vowels;
```

Comment: woooooot! Why the heck I didn't notice this :S

Comment: While this will make the compiler error go away, it is a very wrong thing to do. You should use instance variables and instance data and reserve static members for utility methods and class-level data (for example constants and defaults).

Comment: I'm totally going to agree wholeheartedly @AdamZalcman; it is *far* better to create instances of objects instead of making the entire thing static.  But there's no indication that the static modifier is required as part of the assignment, or not.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use String vowels inside your static methods because vowels is non-static. You need to add static keyword to the string, then your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

you can make the variables static or just keep everything non-static and this will get solved. The bigger question you need to ask your self is when should i use static and when not ?

Comment: if a method doesn't operate on the state of any particular object, it should to be static

Answer (score 0):

change

```
String vowels;
```

to

```
static String vowels;
```

All your methods are static and thus do not require an instance of your object to be present  - ie you don't have to say

```
x = new RecursionHW2(); 
x.upperCase(..);
```

However if you don't make vowels static, it doesn't exist unless an object is instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Static variables belong to the class, the static variables that are not belong to the class instances (objects).

**Test**

```
class Foo {

    private static String vowers;
    private String bar;

}


Foo a = new Foo ()
```

Are creating a new instance of class Foo, each instance has its own variable bar, but all share **vowers** variable because this belongs to the class. Same goes with the static methods.

Within a static method (class method) you can not reference variables that are not static. Why is this so?

imagine that from a static method you reference a variable that is not static

```
class Foo {
    private static String vowers;
    private String bar;

    public static void exampleMethod () {
       bar = "home";
    }

}
```

If you do this:

```
Foo a = new Foo () / / has a new bar
Foo b = new Foo () / / has a new bar
```

vowers is a single variable and belongs to the class not the instance

When you

```
Foo.exampleMethod()
```

The method does not know that variable **bar** used if the variable of instance a or the variable instance of b. Therefore you can only access static variables of the class from a static method